# AngularJS $scope won't update when ng-model is updated

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following html

```
<input id="zoom" name="zoom" style="width:100px" type="text" ng-model="user.zoomlvl">
```

When I run the below it updates the above html input field

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    mapZoom();
});
function mapZoom(){
    valZoom = map.getZoom();
    $('#zoom').val(valZoom);
}
```

But `$scope.user.zoomlvl` still will not update when the `zoom_changed` has updated the input field.

Comment: Just saw your other question related to this too.  As I suspected there you're attempting to use some third-party JS library, in this case Google Maps, you should search around a bit there are a couple of implementations of wrappers for google maps for AngularJS (directives) you can just include in your project and modify as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using events that are not part of Angular (e.g. `zoom_changed`), then they don't run `$scope.$apply()` at the end like `ng-click` would. That's why your `$scope` is not updated. Therefore, in your event you need to add `$scope.$apply()`

```
function mapZoom(){
    valZoom = map.getZoom();
    //$('#zoom').val(valZoom);
    // This is also probably better
    $scope.user.zoom1v1 = valZoom
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to update it outside of the Angular controller?

Comment: Yes, but it would probably require using services with the right dependency injections.